# validation on angular form submit after ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

i need to validate my form on `ng-click` in this way

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">submit</button>
```

and i also have a function which i need to call on `ng-click` which is like

```
<button ng-click="loginCheck(user)">submit</button>Login</button>
```

Im unable to do both in one `ng-click`. any other sollution which i can make

or anything which i could do in my controller

```
$scope.loginCheck = function(user) {
}
```

Comment: you can have more than one argument to ng-click, just use a ";" like so: ng-click="loginCheck(user); submitted=true"

Comment: Try Ng-submit along with it.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: Also try removing the type="submit" from <button< tag